# How to add arbitrary images to the "Photos" app on iPad?

Tags: ipad, photos.app, files.app

I'm using the 6th generation iPad, software version 14.5.1

I have used the iPad's camera to take several photos. These photos appeared in the "Photos" app. Within this app I can create an album and move the taken photos into this album. So far, everything is fine.

Later I ran out of space on this iPad, copied all photos from iPad to my Windows PC and deleted them from iPad.

Now I want to copy some of the photos back to iPad.

I use the "Files" app on iPad to connect to the shared folder on my PC and copy the files from PC to iPad. In the "Files" app I created a folder and put the images on iPad into the folder. So, the files are sitting on the iPad and the "Files" app can see them.

Now I'm trying to move these images back into "Photos" app where they originally were and simply can't find a way to do it.

In the "Photos" app when I try to add photos to an album, the "Photos" app doesn't see the images that the "Files" app can see. In the "Files" app I can select all the images and tap "Share", but the "Photos" app doesn't appear in the list of apps with which I can share the images.

How to add images to the "Photos" app from the "Files" app?

Comment: Do the files you're trying to copy to Photos have an image extension (.bmp, .jpg, etc)?

Comment: Actually you don’t have to copy them to the Files app but could select them on your PC in a shared folder you access from the iPad, select the Share menu and then „Save Image“. This will copy them to the Photos App Library. The same works for the Photos in Files. Select all, open Share-menu, select „Save Image“. Done. 

Comment: @fsb, the images have .HEIC extension - they were taken on that iPad. If I tap on an image in the "Files" app, it shows the picture. Files app recognises that these files are images and knows how to display their contents.

Comment: @slartibartfast, thank you! It is absolutely not obvious that the "Save Image" command is related to the "Photos" app. Some poor UI design choice. Please write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don’t have to copy them to the Files app but could select them on your PC in a shared folder you access from the iPad, select the Share menu and then „Save Image“. This will copy them to the Photos App Library. The same works for the Photos in Files. Select all, open Share-menu, select „Save Image“. Done.